# How do I make the UV flattening geometry node in this video with 3.5 geonodes?

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCZVLTk9d-Y

Geometry nodes have been changed since 2.9 and the node used in the video has been removed. How can I build the same function with the new nodes?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.